# the controls not spread through the width of screen

Tags: android, android-layout, galaxy

I want to create bar of ocntrols that fit throught the whole width of screen , so I used the following code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"  
    android:background="#d9dee1"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:orientation="horizontal" 
          android:background="@drawable/buttonsborder"

        >
     <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:orientation="horizontal" 



        >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Chemo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Chemo" 
            android:background="@drawable/firstbuttoncolorstyle"
             android:textColor="@drawable/firstbuttontextstyle"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/inpatient"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="inpatient" 
            android:background="@drawable/firstbuttoncolorstyle"
             android:textColor="@drawable/firstbuttontextstyle"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Mgmt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Mgmt" 
            android:background="@drawable/firstbuttoncolorstyle"
             android:textColor="@drawable/firstbuttontextstyle"
            />
          </LinearLayout>       
     <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:orientation="horizontal" 

        >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/PFinder"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="PFinder" 
            android:background="@drawable/secondbuttoncolorstyle"
            android:textColor="@drawable/secondbuttontextstyle"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Afinder"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Afinder" 
            android:background="@drawable/secondbuttoncolorstyle"
            android:textColor="@drawable/secondbuttontextstyle"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Calender"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Calender" 
            android:background="@drawable/secondbuttoncolorstyle"
            android:textColor="@drawable/secondbuttontextstyle"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

          <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:orientation="horizontal" 

        >
            <Button
            android:id="@+id/Profile"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Profile" 
             android:background="@drawable/thirdbuttoncolorstyle"
             android:textColor="@drawable/secondbuttontextstyle"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/SODEOD"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SOD/EOD" 
            android:background="@drawable/thirdbuttoncolorstyle"
            android:textColor="@drawable/secondbuttontextstyle"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Clear"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Clear" 

            android:background="@drawable/thirdbuttoncolorstyle"
            android:textColor="@drawable/secondbuttontextstyle"

            />

        </LinearLayout>



                  <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:orientation="horizontal" 

        >
                <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/maillme"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/mail" />


                    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/callme"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/call" />

        </LinearLayout>



     </LinearLayout>

    <!-- the two columns part -->

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.80"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 

        >

        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_weight=".80"
            android:id="@+id/submenue"



            >

             <!-- this will be the menue list -->




            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="First Name" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".20"
            android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
            >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="second Name" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

but the result is as in the following image
[image]

How to spread the controls through the width of screen ( the color buttons), and the list I create on run time of button click using this code

```
this.inpatient = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.inpatient);
    this.inpatient.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String[] MainMenue =  new String[] { "Chemo Unit", "Inpatient", "Patient tests","Management", "Instructions","Profile","Tools"};

            // remove all controls 

            LinearLayout formLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.submenue);
            formLayout.removeAllViews();

            menueview = new ListView(getApplicationContext());               
            menueview.setVisibility(ListView.VISIBLE);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
            menueview.setLayoutParams(params);


            menueview.setAdapter(new submenueadapter(menueview.getContext(), MainMenue));
            formLayout.addView(menueview);
        }
    });
```

how to increase the font , and to fill the height

Answer (score 2):

I think you have two possibilities. 
The first one if you want to keep your LinearLayout:
Give all the children of your sub menu layout_width="match_parent" and set all its layout_weigth to 1.

A second way could be, to use instead of a LinearLayout for the sub menu, this TableLayout:

```
<TableLayout android:id="@+id/TableLayout"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="*">

    <!-- Your menu items -->

    <TableRow android:id="@+id/TableRow" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: can I increase button size bit , also it worked very well, what about the list how to increase it

Comment: Excuse me please but i have problems to understand you. English is not my mothers language as well, but please try to write more clear and use punctuations. Which list you'd like to increase as well?

Comment: as you can see in the image in my question and teh code below it, I add list dynamically but it appea so small, can I increase its font size and make each ist element larger. this is my first question. my second one can I increase the size of the button(I mean the height)

Comment: You can get a bigger font size with style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large" or set an individual text apereance. I'd recommend to use the default android styles. You can make the elements larger using android:minHeight or an absolute one. The same works for the button, but i'd recommend you to use wrap content because minHeights and absolute values do not scale good for different screens.